# Book series where the main characters have powers associated with smells

Tags: story-identification, powers

There is a book series where the main characters (one boy and one girl) have powers. If I remember correctly, the boys powers are associated with the smell of oranges, and the girls powers are associated with the smell of vanilla. What book is this?

Comment: When did you read the series? In what language? How many books do you remember there being in the series? What sort of powers did they have?

Comment: I ready this series, but I only remember there being 4 or 5 books in the series. I also don't remember the specific powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the "[The Secrets of the Immortal Nicholas Flamel](https://www.goodreads.com/series/45732-the-secrets-of-the-immortal-nicholas-flamel)" series by Michael Scott.

*[The Warlock](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8458018-the-warlock)*, 5th book of the series has some textual evidence, but I am assured that it exists throughout the books.

[image: Book cover]

From [this site's summary](https://prezi.com/oca4tj20lyta/the-warlock/) (emphasis mine):

> Josh is one of the main characters in book. He is Sophie's twin brother and one of the twins of legend. He has a pure gold aura, and when he uses it, the **smell of Oranges** fill the air. Josh and his sister split during the story, each taking one side. To Josh, he picked the correct side, but to Sophie he didn't. They become reunited at the end of the book. Sophie Sophie is also a main character in the book. She is Josh's twin sister and is the other twin of legend. She, unlike her brother, has a pure silver aura, and when she uses it, the air fills with the **smell of vanilla**.

A summary from Goodreads of the book (bolding theirs):

> **The twins of prophecy have been divided—the end has begun.**
>
> **Alcatraz**
>   Although their ally Dr. John Dee has been declared utlaga, Machiavelli and Billy the Kid will follow the plans the Elders have laid before them: they will loose the monsters of Alcatraz on the city of San Francisco, thereby triggering the end of the human race.
>
> **Danu Talis:**
>   The Shadowrealm that Scatty and Joan of Arc have entered is far more dangerous than they could ever have imagined. And they haven't landed here by chance—the warriors were called for a reason. So were Saint-Germain, Palamedes, and Shakespeare. The group was summoned because they must travel back int time to Danu Talis to destroy it. For the island of Danu Talis, known in humani myth as the lost city of Atlantis, must fall if the modern world is to exist.
>
> **San Francisco**
>   The end is finally near. Josh Newman has chosen a side, and he will not stand with his sister, Sophie, or with the Alchemyst, Nicholas Flamel. He will fight alongside Dee and the mysterious Virginia Dare.
>
> Unless Sophie can find her twin before the battle begins, all is lost—forever.

And, from [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=CsHiGqDfpaIC&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=the%20warlock%20oranges%20vanilla&source=bl&ots=kg81AZ0y6a&sig=mc7SU4fv9MFfhAZ6qKD3dv0KRbQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS6uuS-J3MAhWIQZoKHfTtD1oQ6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=the%20warlock%20oranges%20vanilla&f=false):

> Her face moved left and right as she sniffed the air. "You can still smell the magic."
> "Vanilla," Isis said.
> "Orange," Osiris added.

Comment: Nicholas Flammel? Is this a Harry Potter book?

Comment: @user13267: [Nicolas Flamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Flamel) is a historical figure who was also an alchemist. He first showed up in fiction in *Indiana Jones and the Philosopher's Stone* which was released two years before the first Harry Potter book.